# What is the difference between innertext and innerText in html?

Tags: html, frontend

If we inspect any element in browser, there are two properties associated with each of them.

1. innertext and
2. innerText

(notice 'T' is caps in second one)

`document.getElementById(elementId).innerText = 'sometext';`

updates inner-text of the element but when I try to do

`document.getElementById(elementId).innertext = 'someOtherText';`

nothing happens.

Is there any difference between the two. If yes, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

`.innertext` method does not exist in plain JS.

Hence, doing `document.getElementById(elementId).innertext = 'someOtherText';` will create a new property called `innertext` for your object with the value you provided.

Answer (score 1):

The innerText property is used by all major browsers, so that should be the one you use.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText

Browsers historically have individually added a large number of non-standard features, and if you are seeing an innertext property, it was likely just added by that browser for convenience.